# Should we make versioned tags for Tor browser?

Tags: discussion, tags

Tor browser is the user facing part of Tor and thus the [tor-browser-bundle](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tor-browser-bundle) tag attracts lots of questions. However over the time this Q&A page exists we saw the major versions 3, 4 and 5 of TBB. Some versions got new features and maybe older features won't work anymore. So I was thinking if we could introduce a TBB-version-tag. This shows which major version is used and we can easily see if one uses an outdated version.

What do you think about this approach? What should the tag look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree.  I think we should keep the [tor-browser-bundle](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tor-browser-bundle) and add [major-version-5](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/major-version-5), etc OR completely get rid of [tor-browser-bundle](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tor-browser-bundle) and replace it with [tbb-major-version-5](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tbb-major-version-5).

I think the first option would be better because it groups all the questions having to do with TBB and all the questions regarding the specific version instead of having 5 different tags.